# Amazon Cloudfront and Exotic File Extensions - Access Denied

Tags: file-extension, amazon-cloudfront, access-denied

Alright, I've run into a weird issue - I have a series of `.unity3d` files on Cloudfront via an S3 bucket, as well as test images, and a `.unity3d.zip` version of one of the files. The `.unity3d` files result in an "Access Denied", but the images and `unity3d.zip` file download just fine.

What's going on, and can I fix it, or must I append/trim .zip to all my unity3d files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out, this is a mis-diagnosis, related to the exotic file extension. When a ".../file.unity3d" address is entered into the address bar of Chrome, it does not replace the webpage previously loaded. If that previous load was an `Access Denied`, you'll still see it.

In more detail:

If you have a malformed URL (a typo, say), OR if you have a restricted access file on S3, you get an Access Denied.

And if you have a file the browser doesn't know how to open, it will **not update the webpage**

So, if you (as I) first visit an address that generates an Access Denied, and *then* visit a valid address with, say, a unity3d file, *in the same tab*, it will appear as though the unity3d address generates another Access Denied, when it doesn't, making the valid address appear invalid.

You can more easily see what's going on via `curl` in the command line.